# About the words in format: ～がかり

Tags: suffixes, morphology, parts-of-speech

What is the type of word `～がかり`, e.g `気{き}がかり`

Is it noun, or adjective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practically all monolingual dictionaries will label 「気がかり」 as both a [名詞]{めいし} and a [形容動詞]{けいようどうし}.

名詞： "noun"

形容動詞： "na-adjective" or "adjectival noun"

> 「Word X + **な** + Noun」

If the phrase above makes sense, then Word X can be called a 形容動詞 according to Japanese "school grammar", which is the main school of grammar that is being taught to our children all over the country as I type this.

Just as 「きれい**な**人 (a beautiful woman)」, 「[元気]{げんき}**な**[子]{こ} (a perky kid)」 and 「[簡単]{かんたん}**な**あいさつ (a brief greeting)」 make perfect sense, 「気がかり**な**こと (a worrying matter)」 is grammatical and it makes perfect sense as well.

Accordingly, 「気がかり」 can certainly be called a 形容動詞 just as 「きれい」, 「元気」 and 「簡単」 can.  Thus, your textbook is correct on this matter.

Comment: That makes the most sense, seems `noun` & `adjectival noun` share a lot things in common.

Answer (score 3):

It's the masu-form of the intransitive verb かかる (*to relate*, *to concern*, etc), used as a noun. 気がかり is a compound noun made of 気 (*mind*) + かかり (*concerning*).

This `noun + masu-form` pattern is very often seen in Japanese nouns. Just to name a few:

- 綱引き (tug of war): 綱 (rope) + 引き (pulling)
- 花見 (cherry-viewing): 花 (flower) + 見 (viewing)
- 爪切り (nail clipper): 爪 (nail) + 切り (cutter)

I don't know whether the verbs in these words can be called suffixes, because most verbs can be turned into nouns in this way. But they function like a suffix, anyway.

Comment: I thought it's noun too. But, in a text book, `気がかり` is said to be `Adjectival noun`, so I am still not sure about that ...

Answer (score 1):

My Japanese dictionary says it's a suffix. Suffixes are called 接尾語 in Japanese.